# Python 3.4 64-bit download

Tags: python, anaconda

How can I download Anaconda with previous Python versions like Python 3.4 64-bit.

The reason is Bloomberg API is only available up to 3.4 and 3.5 is not out yet.

Comment: http://conda.pydata.org/docs/py2or3.html

Comment: https://repo.continuum.io/archive/

Answer (score 7):

I recommend installing the newest Anaconda version and using **virtual-environments**. This way, you would set up a *Python 3.4* environment.

This is documented [here](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html).
There are also [these docs](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/py2or3.html), which are describing mostly the same approach, but are targeting more specifically the python2/3 problem. (Link mentioned in the comments)

So after installing Anaconda (let's assume, condas binaries are in the path:

```
conda create --name py34 python=3.4
```

Then it can be used with

```
source activate py34  # linux
activate py34         # windows
```

During activation (or: while activated), the binaries (python, pip, conda) will be in the path). This means using `conda install matplotlib` will install to the `3.4` version!

After doing:

```
source activate root  # linux
activate root         # windows
```

something like `conda install matplotlib` will install to the base-version.

Comment: Perhaps this is also a useful link to add to this answer: http://conda.pydata.org/docs/py2or3.html#check-python-versions

Comment: This is beyond my expertise.  Any suggestions without virtual environments?

Comment: @MichaelCorcelli [Here](https://repo.continuum.io/archive/index.html) But i really don't recommend installing old versions. But you would also need to recognize which old Anaconda version was bringing up 3.4 by default. This should be in the changelogs (but i can't access these right now; maybe parts of the website are off).

Comment: @MichaelCorcelli Please, do not install an old version of Anaconda that defaults to 3.4. That completely defeats the purpose of Anaconda. That page describes step-by-step instructions to achieve exactly what you want with a virtual environment. If you can read and type, then it is not beyond your expertise. That is one of the major selling points of Anaconda - easy creation and maintenance of virtual environments.

Comment: It's best to not refer to `conda environments` as `virtual environments` as they are distinct things (serving a very similar purpose I admit).

Answer (score 0):

If you are in an environment with Python version 3.4.2, this command will update Python to 3.4.3, which is the latest version in the 3.4 branch

`$ conda update python`

This command will upgrade Python to another branch such as 3.5 by installing that version of Python:

`$ conda install python=3.5`

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend installing the newest Anaconda version and using virtual-environments. This way, you would set up a Python 3.4 environment.

Comment: Using the latest anaconda and creating a virtual environment will not give you python 3.4. There's a difference between a `conda` environment and virtual environment.